# Symfony & Composer Update Not Working

Tags: php, symfony

I am running "composer update" and I keep getting this error:

Problem 1

```
- remove doctrine/orm 2.5.x-dev|keep doctrine/orm dev-master

- doctrine/orm v2.5.0-alpha2 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.

- doctrine/orm v2.5.0-alpha1 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.

- doctrine/orm 2.5.x-dev requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.

- doctrine/orm dev-master requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.

- Installation request for doctrine/orm 2.5.*@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[2.5.x-dev, v2.5.0-alpha1, v2.5.0-alpha2].
```

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "twig/extensions": "1.1.*@dev",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.6.*@dev",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.2.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "dev-master",
    "components/jquery": "~2.1",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "~3.3",
    "datatables/datatables": "~1.10",
    "bmatzner/jquery-ui-bundle": "~1.10",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
     "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "google/wkhtmltopdf-amd64",
            "version": "0.11.0-RC1",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2",
                "type": "tar"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "google/wkhtmltopdf-i386",
            "version": "0.11.0-RC1",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2",
                "type": "tar"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I have tried to change "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*@dev" to everything recommended in the error notice and I always keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: "doctrine/orm": "~2.5"

Comment: I basically got the same error:  Problem 1
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.0-alpha2 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.5.0-alpha1 requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for doctrine/orm ~2.5 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.5.0-alpha1, v2.5.0-alpha2].

Comment: I am on this:

  "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:

https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm

And from here:

https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-bundle

The best choose will be the stable releases:

```
"doctrine/orm": "2.4.7"

"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.0"
```